# Python_ print the result of funcction

Tags: python

I'm a beginner of Python..!
I'm learning how to define a function and how to print out the result.
**I was going to print out only y value of function.**
While practicing, I found weird thing...

if I define function as you see and write the code as below:

```py
def f(x):
    y=3*x+5  
    print(y)
print(f(10))
```

I get the two result as below... :(

```sh
35
None
```

What I want is only the y value. Can you please explain **why None printed out?**

I'm learning Python little by little. Thank you so much..!!

Comment: `y` is not returned, only `print`ed. Use `return` to return it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your codes to return `y` like this:

```
def f(x):
    y=3*x+5
    return y
print(f(10))
```

Since your original codes do not return `y`, `f(10)` returns `None` (the value of `y`), which leads to your second result being `None`. The first result from your original codes (which is 35) is from the `print` function inside your `def f(x)`.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I was wondering how the results of 35 and None came from,  I could easily understand because you kindly explained it to me!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the value of y

```
def f(x):

    y=3*x+5
    return y

print(f(10))
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I will learn about the return function step by step!! Thank you!!

Comment: No problem! Happy to help! :)